# If $X_0,X_1,X_2,...$ be a Markov chain then why $Z_n=X_0X_1...X_n$ is also a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

If $X_0,X_1,X_2,...$ is a Markov chain then why is $Z_n=X_0X_1...X_n$ also a Markov chain?

Could you explain briefly?

Many thanks**

Comment: Thanks for edit. I appologise that I do not know how to type like you did.

Comment: I think you could try and check the definition of markov chain against $Z_n $. My guess would be that it should be simple to show that  $Z_n $ complies with the definition.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true.

For isntance: let $(X_n)$ be the Markov chain defined as follows:  Let $P(X_0=1)=P(X_0=2)=\frac{1}{2}$, and determine $X_{n+1}$ from $X_n$ using the transition probabilities
$$
p_{11}=\frac{1}{4},\quad p_{12}=\frac{3}{4},\quad p_{21}=\frac{1}{2},\quad p_{22}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
You can show that for $Z_i:=\prod_{j\leq i}X_i$,
$$
P(Z_2=4\mid Z_0=1,Z_1=2)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
while
$$
P(Z_2=4\mid Z_0=2, Z_1=2)=\frac{3}{4}.
$$
If $(Z_n)$ were a Markov chain, then we would need to have
$$
P(Z_2=4\mid Z_0=1,Z_1=2)=P(Z_2=4\mid Z_1=2)=P(Z_2=4\mid Z_0=2, Z_1=2).
$$

Fundamentally, the problem with your assertion is this: knowledge of $Z_n$ is not enough to produce good knowledge of $X_n$ (it is only information about $X_n/X_{n-1}$ essentially), but knowledge of $Z_0,\ldots, Z_n$ IS enough to produce knowledge about $X_0,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: What if the question was 
If $X_0,X_1,X_2,...$ is a Markov Chain and $Z_n=X_0X_1...X_n$, explain why $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,...$ is a Markov Chain?

Comment: @ʎpoqou How is that different than the question that was initially asked?

Comment: In the question I ask, you consider a sequence of $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,...$. Unless you also assumed the op meant that this is the sequence to be considered. In any case. What if I added that each $X_i$ has a state space {0,1}?

Comment: @ʎpoqou That is precisely the sequence considered in the question above, yes.  However, in the very special case you've just mentioned, it does turn out to be a Markov chain.  Note that $Z_n\in\{0,1\}$ for all $n$, and think about the probability of transition between these states.  If you have further questions, though, please don't follow up here; that's not what comments are for. Instead, ask an actual question!